# Where should a click listener be in a recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

item of my recycler view has some different views which has to have a click listener if i add a click listener to recycler view with view and position parameters it always take the layout behind the views on click. Therefore, i am setting my click listeners in onBindViewHolder like this:

```
holder.myTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // stuff
        }
    });

holder.myImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // stuff
        }
    });
```

I wonder whether it is a correct method?

Comment: I think that depends on what you're doing in your onclick methods. I can't see anything wrong with this approach.

Comment: Yes this is the correct method, i am also using the same method for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where should a click listener be in a recycler view?

There are many ways for achieve this, but ;

Both is correct as i see on your codes.Means, if you set those items with `myTextView`, the users will be able to click on `TextView` (f.g) for showing that `RecyclerView` item content or whatever and other stuffs like `ImageView` won't work for listener.

And this is correct for `myImageView` too, if you set those items with it for listener, the users will be able to click **only** in this `myImageView`.

By the way, ***i think it is better*** to use `implements View.OnClickListener` **for whole of the `Holder`.**

Something like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24471410/4409113

or Jacob's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick/26196831#26196831)

Comment: thank u, also, is there a big performance difference between implementing a view.onclicklistener and setting listeners in onbindviewholder for each item?

Comment: Yes i hope so, i was doing the same thing for each item like you said, and i  just thought about it, seems like that makes sense, imagine it, we could use whole of `RowHolder` instead of those duplicates or bad way.A lot of codes for handling an easy way sounds crazy, right? :)

Comment: in jacob's answer when i try onclick method with view.getClass() it always return linearlayout which is the background. It does not detect the buttons or other views in front of the layout.

Comment: it works thank you so much. I appreciate it if you check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818380/imagedetailsactivity-for-a-recycler-view